# SharedPreferences in separate class

Tags: android

I'm having trouble calling SharedPreferences in a non activity class. Unfortunately I don't get any errors in Android Studio, but saveList() never executes properly.

```
public class UDP_Client {
...

public void UDPBroatcast() {

    async_cient = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

...
        listenForResponses(ds);

    }
  }
}


private void listenForResponses(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                String s = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
                String ipaddress = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                if (!(ipaddress.equals(ownIPAddress))) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received response: " + s + " From IP: " + ipaddress);
                }
                arrayList.add(ipaddress);
                Log.d(TAG, "Added IP:" + ipaddress + " to ArrayList");
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Receive timed out");
            SaveIPs.saveList(); //Calling saveList after timeout
        }
    }    

...

public static class SaveIPs {

    private final Context context;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    public SaveIPs(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Found_Devices", 0);
    }

    private static void saveList() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        Object[] mStringArray = arrayList.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
            Log.d("Saving storage position " + i + " to", (String) mStringArray[i]);
            edit.putString("Server" + i, (String) mStringArray[i]);
        }
        edit.commit();
    }
   }
}
```

Any idea?

I left out some code for overview purpose.

LogCat:

```
07-22 13:02:32.891    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Own IP Address: 192.168.0.117
07-22 13:02:33.282    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Sending data: <cmd="discover" application="liquidbeam_remote" challenge="myUDP" signature="5e6198975160345df82aa6085ebf7e9c"/>
07-22 13:02:33.282    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control E/UDP Discovery﹕ Data sent:Messageto IP: 192.168.0.255
07-22 13:02:33.292    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Added IP:192.168.0.117 to ArrayList
07-22 13:02:33.322    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Received response: Hallo!!! From IP: 192.168.0.134
07-22 13:02:33.322    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Added IP:192.168.0.134 to ArrayList
07-22 13:02:34.323    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control D/UDP Discovery﹕ Receive timed out
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client$SaveIPs.saveList(UDP_Client.java:201)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client$SaveIPs.access$200(UDP_Client.java:190)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client.listenForResponses(UDP_Client.java:118)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client.access$100(UDP_Client.java:36)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client$1.doInBackground(UDP_Client.java:75)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client$1.doInBackground(UDP_Client.java:57)
07-22 13:02:34.333    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-22 13:02:34.343    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-22 13:02:34.343    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-22 13:02:34.343    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-22 13:02:34.343    5232-5271/de.liquidbeam.LED.control W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Debuging arrayList:

```
this = {de.liquidbeam.LED.control.fragments.UDP_Client@830044849896}
socket = {java.net.DatagramSocket@830044852416}
buf = {byte[1024]@830045006728}
packet = {java.net.DatagramPacket@830045008808}
s = {java.lang.String@830045009744}"Hallo!!!"
ipaddress = {java.lang.String@830045009816}"192.168.0.134"
arrayList = {java.util.ArrayList@830044849872} size = 2
[0] = {java.lang.String@830045008192}"192.168.0.117"
[1] = {java.lang.String@830045009816}"192.168.0.134"
```

Comment: What does "never executes properly" mean? Any logs, exceptions, etc.?

Comment: it crashes for NullPointerException

Comment: It does not crash at all. It should execute saveList() after the timeout but it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because first you need to initialize the SaveIPs class constructor. 
Remove static modifier from class as:

> public class SaveIPs { // static its not required hopefully:

then in catch block

```
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) 
      {
             Log.d(TAG, "Receive timed out");
             SaveIPs saveip_obj = new SaveIPs(context)//pass the context here  
             saveip_obj.saveList();

      }
```

You might not be having any data in pref because the `sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Found_Devices", 0);`

was not getting called.
If this is not the reason would like to know the line no. at which its pointing towards Nullpointer Exception

Comment: Thanks, no static is not required. I removed the static parameters in the class. Unfortunately a "context can't be resolved" error accrued with your code suggestion.

Comment: ofcourse it will. you need to pass the context of the application i.e. now in your code you need to see from where you can get the activity context as by this only you can retrieve the sharedprefs object

Comment: "sharedPrefs = null" is causing the Nullpointer Exception, I think. It seems like I've got some major issues with the code. I'll need investigate further...

Comment: public class UDP_Client {
 Context context;

public UDP_Client(Context context){
 this.context=context;
}  now from wherever you call this UDPClient you need to initialize it first by passing a context. This will resolve you sharedprefs being null. its throwing null because its not receiving a valid context. If you agree please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Had to add (in fragment activity): UDP_Client udpDiscoverer = new UDP_Client(getActivity()); udpDiscoverer.UDPBroatcast();

Answer (score 1):

Here my understanding is you have to call saveList method after the getting data from the socket connection,that means you can call saveList method after catch block or  create a finally block and inside  of this block.

I think ArrayList variable arrayList is null so only it throws NullPointerException.Check the data from the socket connection you are getting data or null.

Comment: Thanks, but arrayList is not null. I added some debug info.

Comment: You can check the shared preferences and initialize the  saveIp class and with context. Create construtor in saveIp class and then call saveList method ,get shared preferences value.